# Artifacts in 3D transparent surfaces produced by Asymptote

Tags: asymptote

Here is MWE demonstrating my typical rendering issue

```
settings.outformat = "png";
settings.render=1;
real scale=400pt;
size(scale,0);

import graph3;
currentprojection = perspective(100*dir(45,30));

path3 crossSection = Circle(r=2, c=(5,0,0), normal=Y);
surface torus = surface(crossSection, c=(0,0,0), axis=Z);
draw(torus, red+opacity(0.5));
```

This produces for me the following image.

[image]

Internet search revealed that this is a known bug related to the system configuration. However, I still don't understand what should I do to obtain the proper images (I have no idea how computer graphics works, OpenGL says nothing to me)? I have several figures that I need to compile in a clean way.

Comment: For this specific example you can reduce the mesh number with `path3 crossSection = Circle(r=2, c=(5,0,0), normal=Y,10);`

Comment: Transparency in Asymptote does not work very well with rasterized output. Workarounds I know: Do without transparency (recommended if possible), remove the back part of the surface, or use `settings.render = 0;`.